# Quit function in python program

Tags: python

I have a program that runs in Python, without the console present (which is to say, I've compiled it using py2exe). I want people to be able to quit from the main menu, or by a particular key-press in-game (say, Shift+Q). I'm running it, for now, in Windows, though I am working on compiling Linux/Mac versions. Pressing the X button works if there's no 'while' loop running, it seems, and that closes it correctly, otherwise it seems to 'store' the close command wait until the current loop is closed.

As for menu options, I've looked thoroughly through documentation and Stackoverflow and tried quit(), exit(), sys.exit() and every combination I can find, but every time I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alphatime.pyw", line 61177, in <module>
  File "alphatime.pyw", line 53970, in place_menu
NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined
```

if I try sys.exit, and then:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alphatime.pyw", line 61177, in <module>
  File "alphatime.pyw", line 53970, in place_menu
NameError: global name 'quit' is not defined
```

if I try just "quit()". I've heard about 'Raising' things like a need to close the program, but I'm not clear what that means (I'm new to Python) and how I would go about doing that.

So, my question is two-fold.

Firstly, is there something I can put in loops for recognizing keypresses something that will recognize the 'X' being clicked, and close?

Secondly, is there an appropriate command that will just close the program? I cannot figure out why these commands don't work, and I've had quite a few complaints from people using the program that it crashes, or they have to ctrl-alt-del it, or whatever. I believe

```
import os
try:
  os._exit(return_code)
except:
  pass
```

would work, but at this point, I'm not sure I'm competent enough at python to deploy it appropriately. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you could use a signal, or just use 2 threads, the main one would wait for closing event and quit, terminating the other thread that does all the rest.

Comment: whaat? he said he was a beginner don't confuse him just yet. :)

Comment: I confess, my eyes glazed a little at that :). But the first problem is now solved, though I'm still puzzled by the 'X' button issue.

Comment: the x is 'inbuilt'.. it will invoke a quit event whenever it is pressed as long as there is a line that breaks the loop or terminates the program. if you add sys.quit() the x button should work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by there being a line that breaks the loop. I'm using the libtcod library, and it has a function called wait_for_keypress (self-explanatory). I have a loop that while something is true, it'll wait for a keypress, and the if/elifs that handle it are only for specific keypresses. What would I want to put in there to handle the X? And where would I put the sys.quit()? Thanks! Have done so, also :).

Comment: the sys.quit() would come after the mainloop usually or anywhere else you might want to prematurely terminate the program. by line that breaks the loop see this example -> http://bpaste.net/show/iNukaBlsSmmvLqEZb5pe/

Comment: Ah, clever - I see. So, if one option in the loop lead onto another function and I left the loop behind, the quit after the loop would just never be called, right? And then that would get the 'X' responding to the quit?

EDIT: I've tried putting a quit outside the loop, but pressing the X button still doesn't call it :S

Comment: hmm. im not sure. perhaps just do what you know for now, use a key or such to close the program until you get a bit better understanding of the topic, i can't help you much beyond the example i gave because im not familiar with the library you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you by any chance

```
import sys
```

because that should work!

Comment: Ah! I'd been doing "from sys" and getting exit, but not getting all sys. How embarrassing. My thanks!

But hitting the 'X' button still doesn't work in the main menu. Is there a way to 'catch' it?

Answer (score 3):

> NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined

Before you can use `sys.exit()`, you must `import sys`.

That's the best way to exit the program. Function names that begin with `_` are considered internal, and should not be used unless you are *really* trying to do something weird.